# stable sort in almost sorted array

Tags: sorting

12. Which of the following stable sorting algorithm takes the least time when applied to an almost sorted array?
    a) Quick sort
    b) Insertion sort
    c) Selection sort
    d) Merge sort

why the answer is merge sort not insertion sort?

Comment: merge sort is like `O(log n)` while insertion sort is `O(n^2)` no? wait, is this homework?

Comment: Where is this problem taken from? What does the given answer say?

Comment: in almost  sorted array, insertion sort need O(n).where merge sort always need O(nlogn) and both are stable sort, so why not insertion sort is the answer ,its not my homework.

Comment: my bad, didn't think much that its about almost sorted array. i'd bet whoever made the answer sheet also missed it.